# Почему не выводится фото?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть база данных в ней хранится имя фото пример(background.jpg) я вытаскиваю его и приписываю к путю вывода фото, фото не выводится в чем ошибка? Вот код;

```
$sqll = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM foto ORDER BY id DESC");
  while ($dd= mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqll)) {
    echo '<div>';
    echo "<img src='/img/foto/'>".$dd["name_file_all"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sqll = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM foto ORDER BY id DESC");
  while ($dd= mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqll)) {
    echo '<div>';
    echo "<img src='/img/foto/".$dd['name_file_all']."'/>";
}
```